# Arangodb Arangoimp using default endpoint

Tags: connection, arangodb, endpoint, arangoimport

I'm using arangodb 3.1.25.
I run in using as the default endpoint is in use and cause me a problem . 
Now that I'm trying to import a dataset to arangodb ,  I see that Arangoimp is still using the default endpoint which is  'tcp://127.0.0.                                                            1:8529' how can I fix this .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try the parameter `--server.endpoint`